# Dictionary update overwrites duplicate keys

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6, updates

I have a table that has 6982 records that I am reading through to make a dictionary. I used a literal to  create the dictionary

```
fld_zone_dict = dict()
fields = ['uniqueid', 'FLD_ZONE', 'FLD_ZONE_1']
...
for row in cursor:
    uid = row[0]
    old_zone_value = row[1]
    new_zone_value = row[2]
    fld_zone_dict[uid] = [old_zone_value, new_zone_value]
```

However, I noticed that using this method, if a uid has the same value as a previous `uid` (theoretically, there could be duplicate), the entry gets overwritten. So, if I had 2 entries I wanted to add: `'CA10376036': ['AE', 'X']` and `'CA10376036': ['V', 'D']`, the first one gets overwritten and I only get  `'CA10376036': ['V', 'D']`. How can I add to my dictionary with out overwriting the duplicate keys so that I get something like this?

```
fld_zone_dict = {'CA10376036': ['AE', 'X'], 'CA9194089':['D', 'X'],'CA10376036': ['V', 'D']....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There is no way to have duplicate keys in a dictionary object in Python.

However, if you were to restructure your data and take that key and put it inside of a dictionary that is nested in a list, you could have duplicate IDs. EX:

```
[
    {
        "id": "CA10376036",
        "data: ['AE', 'X']
    },
    {
        "id": "CA10376036",
        "data: ['V', 'D']
    },
]
```

Doing this though will negate any benefits of lookup speed and ease.

edit: blhsing also has a good example of how to restructure data with a reduced initial lookup time, though you would still have to iterate through data to get the record you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Dicts are not allowed to have duplicate keys in Python. You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to convert existing keys to a list instead:

```
for row in cursor:
    uid = row[0]
    old_zone_value = row[1]
    new_zone_value = row[2]
    fld_zone_dict.setdefault(uid, []).append([old_zone_value, new_zone_value])
```

so that `fld_zone_dict` will become like:

```
{'CA10376036': [['AE', 'X'], ['V', 'D']], 'CA9194089': ['D', 'X'], ...}
```

but then other keys will not have a list of lists as values, so you probably should convert them all instead:

```
for k, v in fld_zone_dict.items():
    fld_zone_dict[k] = [v]
for row in cursor:
    uid = row[0]
    old_zone_value = row[1]
    new_zone_value = row[2]
    fld_zone_dict[uid].append([old_zone_value, new_zone_value])
```

so that `fld_zone_dict` will become like:

```
{'CA10376036': [['AE', 'X'], ['V', 'D']], 'CA9194089': [['D', 'X']], ...}
```